# Is it safe to re-run `ddrescue` if previous run was device-to-device using `-f`?

Tags: ddrescue

I initiated the following:

```
ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc mapfile
```

After 4 days I got a "Finished". The mapfile contains:

```
# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.26
# Command line: ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc mapfile
# Start time:   2022-05-09 17:49:25
# Current time: 2022-05-14 05:33:32
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0xD6C5FE00     +               3
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0xBAA15000  +
0xBAA15000  0x00001000  -
0xBAA16000  0x0002B000  +
0xBAA41000  0x00002000  -
0xBAA43000  0x00012000  +
0xBAA55000  0x00001000  -
0xBAA56000  0x00001000  +
0xBAA57000  0x00001000  -
0xBAA58000  0x000EA000  +
0xBAB42000  0x00003400  -
0xBAB45400  0x0021CC00  +
0xBAD62000  0x00001000  -
0xBAD63000  0x000DA000  +
0xBAE3D000  0x00005000  -
0xBAE42000  0x00003000  +
0xBAE45000  0x00001000  -
0xBAE46000  0x00107000  +
0xBAF4D000  0x00001000  -
0xBAF4E000  0x00005000  +
0xBAF53000  0x00002000  -
0xBAF55000  0x00005000  +
0xBAF5A000  0x00004000  -
0xBAF5E000  0x02377000  +
0xBD2D5000  0x00000400  -
0xBD2D5400  0x00000C00  +
0xBD2D6000  0x00001400  -
0xBD2D7400  0x00009C00  +
0xBD2E1000  0x00001000  -
0xBD2E2000  0x000E1000  +
0xBD3C3000  0x00004000  -
0xBD3C7000  0x192C8000  +
0xD668F000  0x00001000  -
0xD6690000  0x00450000  +
0xD6AE0000  0x00001000  -
0xD6AE1000  0x000B8000  +
0xD6B99000  0x00002200  -
0xD6B9B200  0x739A06AE00  +
```

I'd like to try again (to re-try the errors a few more times).
Will the `-f` cause the mapfile to be ignored and overwrite my last recovery so far? Or can I simply re-run the last command (as above)?

Sorry if I'm missing something. I'm having a tough time fully understanding how my situation with `-f` and device-to-device (rather than to image file) applies to the docs.

Comment: I answered below, this comment is a side note. What if `ddrescue` ignored the mapfile and started anew? We don't expect it to write *random* data to `/dev/sdc`, do we? If it started anew, it would read from `/dev/sdb` *again*, so it would start overwriting `/dev/sdc` with data that is *already there*. It could erase the mapfile though, but you can save a copy beforehand just in case. So save a copy of the mapfile and just try. If you see `ddrescue` immediately at 99% then you will know. If it starts anew then my answer is wrong, still the copy on your `/dev/sdc` won't be invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I simply re-run the last command?

Yes. From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue) [emphasis mine]:

> `-f`
> `--force`
>
> Force overwrite of `outfile`. Needed when `outfile` is not a regular file, but a device or partition. **This option is just a safeguard to prevent the inadvertent destruction of partitions**, and is ignored for regular files.

"*Just* a safeguard", so nothing more than a safeguard. The option just tells `ddrescue` you know what you're doing when specifying `/dev/sdc` as the `outfile`. In effect the tool starts without trying to save you from your potential mistake. The option does not change the way `ddrescue` works *after* it starts. `ddrescue` is designed not to ignore the mapfile, `-f` changes nothing in this regard.

Comment: Great info. Thank you. Executed as expected. Jumped to 99.99 and is re-trying. Appreciate the support. Well described. I'll use this info often. Cheers.